# Can I pass the data from the created Excel file to the listener?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I registered a global event in `AppServiceProvider` as per the docs: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#global-event-listeners :

```
Writer::listen(BeforeWriting::class, function () {
//
});
```

Can I get the data from the exported file?

For example if the event was triggered by the `download` method, then get the filename:

```
public function export() 
{
    return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
}
```

So in the listener I will be able to get `invoices.xlsx`

Comment: On line 185 of [`Writer`](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/9e5b7caaa51043085014d5f67fd6ec0a27ac0beb/src/Writer.php#L81-L128) class, you can see it is sending `$this->exportable` and it is `$export`, so you should be able to add a parameter like this: `Writer::listen(BeforeWriting::class, function ($parameter) {` and `dump` it, so you can see what it is, it should have the data you want (the exporter)

Comment: thanks, I did it, it dumps a `PhpSpreadsheet` object (the underlying package of Laravel-Excel). Still trying to figure where the name is because couldn't find. Also, do you think it will be possible to get the route from which the `export()` was called?

Comment: If you mean to get the line of code and file, that is way harder and requires you to do some weird stuff on the code, so no, do not rely on that solution. I am not sure about the name, I have never used that library and I just checked the documentation and the source code and did not find much. Why are you having these issues? Like, what is triggering the export? Seems you don't have control over that line, right?

Comment: yes pretty much no control over that unless I do a huge refactoring. I was sure that if the `BeforeWriting` event is dispatched, then it already holds the file name that was sent to it via the `new InvoicesExport..` because it has this information

Comment: In that case, it depends on the package's author implementation, there is not much you can do without adding new code

Comment: thank you, I will then work on a refactor